# Is there a way in Django to always CAST a specific Field to VARCHAR?

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc, freetds, django-2.2, sql-variant

**Background Situation Description:**

I'm creating a Django2 application which use a Microsoft SQL Server as back-end database. This database has several tables (which I cannot manage or change them) containing `SQL_VARIANT` fields. This fields contains either an empty string or a number (They are used as Primary Key or as Foreign Key)

**Problem:**

On MSSQL when you make a `JOIN` using a `SQL_VARIANT` field and a `VARCHAR` field, it yields an row empty result, to solve this you have to explicitly convert the SQL_VARIANT field to VARCHAR using `CAST([Table Name].[SQL_VARIANT Field Name] AS VARCHAR`

**Goal:**

I want to find a way to do the `CAST([Table Name].[SQL_VARIANT Field Name] AS VARCHAR` every time Django makes a `JOIN` on the QuerySet or calls a `SQL_VARIANT` field on the QuerySet

How can I accomplish this?

**Code as reference:**

In my problem I'm using 3 tables from MSSQL Database (Vendor, Product and Product Ledger Entry)

Vendor Table

```
create table [Vendor]
(
    Id sql_variant not null primary key, 
    Name varchar(30) not null,
    Address varchar(30) not null,
    City varchar(30) not null,
    Contact varchar(30) not null,
    Type int not null,
    Category int not null,
)
```

Product Table

```
create table [Product]
(
    Id varchar(20) not null primary key,
    Description varchar(60) not null,
    Class varchar(10) not null,
    [Vendor Id] varchar(20) not null,
)
```

Product Ledger Entry table

```
create table [Product Ledger Entry]
(
    Id int not null primary key,
    [Product Id] varchar(20) not null,
    [Posting Date] datetime not null,
    [Entry Type] int not null,
    [Source Id] varchar(20) not null,
    [Document Id] varchar(20) not null,
    Quantity decimal(38,20) not null,
)
```

If I wanted to transverse all 3 tables, I would do ...

```
SELECT
       [Vendor].[Id],
       [Vendor].[Name],
       [Product].[Id],
       [Product Ledger Entry].Quantity
FROM [Vendor]
    INNER JOIN [Product] ON ([Vendor].[Id] = [Product].[Vendor Id])
    INNER JOIN [Product Ledger Entry] ON ([Product].[Id] = [Product Ledger Entry].[Product Id])
```

However this query doesn't yield any rows. Only by making a explicit cast over the `SQL_VARIANT` field, this query shows the excepted result.

```
SELECT
       [Vendor].[Id],
       [Vendor].[Name],
       [Product].[Id],
       [Product Ledger Entry].Quantity
FROM [Vendor]
    INNER JOIN [Product] ON (CAST([Vendor].[Id] AS VARCHAR(20)) = [Product].[Vendor Id])
    INNER JOIN [Product Ledger Entry] ON ([Product].[Id] = [Product Ledger Entry].[Product Id])
```

The same thing happends when you use Django, here are the models:

```
class Vendor(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(db_column='Id', primary_key=True, , max_length=20)

    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=30)

    # Address Description
    address = models.CharField(db_column='Address', max_length=30)

    # Province/City/Municipality
    city = models.CharField(db_column='City', max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Vendor'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id} | {self.name}'
```

```
class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(db_column='No_', primary_key=True, max_length=20)

    description = models.CharField(db_column='Description', max_length=60)

    vendor_id = models.ForeignKey(
        'Vendor', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        db_column='Vendor Id', to_field='id', related_name='products', db_index=False, blank=True
    )

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Product'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id}'
```

```
class ProductLedgerEntry(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Id', primary_key=True)

    product_id = models.ForeignKey(
        'Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        db_column='Product Id', to_field='id', related_name='ledger_entries', db_index=False
    )

    posting_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Posting Date')

    ENTRY_TYPE = [
        (0, 'Compra'),
        (1, 'Venta'),
        (2, 'Ajuste positivo'),
        (3, 'Ajuste negativo'),
        (4, 'Transferencia'),
        (5, 'Consumo'),
        (6, 'Salida desde fab.'),
    ]
    entry_type = models.IntegerField(
        db_column='Entry Type', choices=ENTRY_TYPE
    )

    quantity = models.DecimalField(db_column='Quantity', max_digits=38, decimal_places=20)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Product Ledger Entry'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.product_id} | {self.variant_code} | {self.posting_date}'
```

As long as I don't make use of annotate(...), select_related(...) or any other Django API methond that makes `JOIN` under the hood, I can manage to get proper results. However, I want to use annotate.

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the only way to make this possible would be to fork the SQL Server backend you are using (presumably `django-pyodbc-azure`) to insert an override when it detects the `SQL_VARIANT` field.

However, that feels like a pretty bad idea; as the book "Two Scoops of Django" says, avoid the temptation to create a FrankenDjango! Your underlying tables aren't created by Django; in my experience, it is best to use raw SQL for tables that aren't created and managed by Django. You can use a mix of ORM for tables managed or created by Django, and raw SQL for legacy tables created outside of Django.

Using bound parameters through Django's `execute()` method still gives you SQL injection protection: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

Good luck!